# $lookup returns an empty array mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using the following code with $lookup function.

```
        postSchemaModel.aggregate([{
            "$geoNear": {
                "near": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [6.7336665, 79.8994071], "Typology": "post" },
                "distanceField": "dist.calculated",
                "maxDistance": 5000,
                "includeLocs": "dist.location",
                "spherical": true
            }
        },
        { "$limit": limit },
        { "$skip": startIndex },
        { "$sort": { "createdAt": -1 } },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": userSchemaModel.collection.name,
                "localField": "user_id",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "user_id"
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "post_data": 1,
                "likes": 1,
                "commentsCount": 1,
                "post_img": 1,
                "isUserLiked": 1,
                "usersLiked": 1,
                'exp_date': 1,
                "has_img": 1,
                "user_id": "$user_id",
                "typology": 1,
                "geometry": 1,
                "category": 1,
                "created": 1,
                "createdAt": 1,
                "updatedAt": 1,
            }
        },
    ]).then(async function(posts) {
        //some code here
    });
```

The problem is this gives me an empty array for ***user_id***. The following is one output I receive.

```
{ _id: 5ee1f89732fd2c33bccfec55,
    post_data: 'vvhhh',
    likes: 1,
    commentsCount: 0,
    post_img: null,
    isUserLiked: false,
    usersLiked: [ 5edf43b93859680cf815e577 ],
    exp_date: 2020-06-12T18:30:00.000Z,
    has_img: false,
    typology: 'chat',
    geometry:
     { pintype: 'Point',
       _id: 5ee1f89732fd2c33bccfec56,
       coordinates: [Array] },
    category: [],
    created: 1591867543468,
    createdAt: 2020-06-11T09:25:43.478Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-06-15T10:01:01.133Z,
    user_id: [] }
```

In my case I don't want it to be null and I am expecting a output like below.

```
{ _id: 5ee1f89732fd2c33bccfec55,
post_data: 'vvhhh',
likes: 1,
commentsCount: 0,
post_img: null,
isUserLiked: false,
usersLiked: [ 5edf43b93859680cf815e577 ],
exp_date: 2020-06-12T18:30:00.000Z,
has_img: false,
typology: 'chat',
geometry:
 { pintype: 'Point',
   _id: 5ee1f89732fd2c33bccfec56,
   coordinates: [Array] },
category: [],
created: 1591867543468,
createdAt: 2020-06-11T09:25:43.478Z,
updatedAt: 2020-06-15T10:01:01.133Z,
user_id:  { img: 'default-user-profile-image.png',
   _id: 5edd103214ce223088a59236,
   user_name: 'Puka' }
}
```

My userSchema is something like below

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
//some other fields
    user_name: {
        type: String,
        max: 30,
        min: 5
    },

    img: {
        type: String,
        default: 'default-user-profile-image.png'

    },
//some other fields
});
userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
var userSchemaModel = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);

module.exports = {
    userSchemaModel,
}
```

According to the other answers here I tried using ***mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId),*** but it gives complete empty set.

What can be the problem here and it will be really helpful if someone can help me with this as I'm stuck with this for days.

Update :
post schema

```
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        ref: 'users'
    },
//other fields
var postSchemaModel = mongoose.model('posts', postSchema);
module.exports = {
    postSchemaModel,
}
```

Comment: what's the schema of postSchemaModel?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are storing post.user_id as `String` and not `ObjectId`? Are you allowed to change it to `ObjectId`?

Comment: @thammada I also  used `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` but the result is same. Empty

Comment: You have to change the existing data as well, not just the schema

Comment: @thammada Thank you very much. It is working after I changed to ObjectId and cleaned the collections. Appreciate <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data type of `user._id`(`ObjectId`) and `post.user_id`(`String`) are not the same you can not join those fields using `$lookup`. You have to make sure they are the same type before doing `$lookup`

If you are allowed to change the schema, it's recommended to use `ObjectId` for `post.user_id`

```
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    // ...other fields
```

But do remember to change the existing data type to `ObjectId` as well.

If you are *really not allowed* to change the schema and existing data, for some reason. You can convert the post.user_id to `ObjectId` in case that the data contains valid hexadecimal representation of `ObjectId` (available from MongoDB v4.0)

```
[
// prior pipeline stages
{ "$sort": { "createdAt": -1 } },
{
  "$addFields": {
    "user_id": { "$toObjectId": "$user_id" }
  }
},
{
  "$lookup": {
    "from": userSchemaModel.collection.name,
    "localField": "user_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "user_id"
  }
},
// other stages
```

Answer (score -1):

As the `_id` field in mongodb is stored as type `ObjectId` but in the `posts` collection `user_id` is stored as type `string`, therefore it is not able find the user information and bring blank array.

To resolve this save a plain string version of `_id` in `user` collection when a user is created. for example

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectId("5ee1f89732fd2c33bccfec55"),
  doc_id: "5ee1f89732fd2c33bccfec55",
  //other user info
}
```

and then use this `doc_id` field in $lookup

```
{
  "$lookup": {
      "from": userSchemaModel.collection.name,
      "localField": "user_id",
      "foreignField": "doc_id",
      "as": "user_id"
  }
}
```

In this way both `user_id` and `doc_id` will be of type `string` and will not need any type conversion hassles.