# Mongodb $lookup returns empty array even with same type

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lookup

I have two collections, one is bugs and the other is project. I tried joining the project on the bug but it returns an empty array. My issue is the same as this [$lookup returns an empty array mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445482/lookup-returns-an-empty-array-mongoose). The only difference is that the types of localField and foreign field is the same.

Here's my aggregation:

```
  Bug.aggregate([
  //get all bugs that match the project id present in array
  { $match: { project: { $in: objectIdArray } } },
  //group all bugs by the same project id
  {
    $group: { _id: "$project", records: { $push: "$$ROOT" } },
  },

  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "project",
      localField: "project",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "project_info",
    },
  },
]).exec(function (err, bugs) {
  if (err) res.status(400).json(err);
  res.json(bugs);
});
```

Here's the project field in bug model:

```
project: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Project" },
```

What am I missing?

Comment: After the `$group` step there is no localField: `project`. There is `$_id.project`, use this as the localField

Comment: Slight typo in @nimrodserok's comment above. Indeed the `project` field no longer exists after the `$group`, which you can confirm by running the pipeline without the `$lookup` (or, really, with it as well). But the field that does exist at that point is just `_id` which is what you should use as the value for the `localField`

Comment: @nimrodserok I got you. I changed local field to _id and it still returns an empty array. The result is like: 
project_info: []
records: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
_id: "634d1c3dfb8d33f1a0073519"

Comment: @user20042973 This is my first item in the records array.  

bugType: ""
createdOn: "2022-10-19T06:49:40.008Z"
dueDate: "2022-10-14T00:00:00.000Z"
project: "634d1c3dfb8d33f1a0073519"
title: "Ticket 1".  Look how the project field is the same as the _id field. For assurance, I also tried by removing the $group and it still returns an empty array.

Comment: @nimrodserok It got fixed!! Thanks for the comment! I was providing project instead of projects in the $from field.